# Combining multiple Twitter user timelines into one request

Tags: php, twitter

I am relatively new to the twitter API so the question might seem foolish but please help me out.

I am trying to get tweets from user's timeline using their API, which I know is possible.

Now the issue is I have to get tweets from multiple users (combining upto 30-40 users) timelines into one API request. How can I do this?

Would the streaming API help? I couldn't make heads or tail of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add those users to a list and pull the [timeline for the list](https://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/%3auser/lists/%3aid/statuses).

Comment: As i understand it, this is only possible from a user perspective is it possible to create public lists without signing in as a user?

Comment: Yep. You might have to create a bot account to create the list and pull it in.