# Fetch multiple twitter users timeline for no-authenticate account

Tags: twitter

Is there a way for no-authenticate user to managed his own list (in code) say I have a list of user screen name, is there any api that can I pass the list of users and return timeline for those users ? I have look into https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline but multiple user is not supported and in this post [Combining multiple Twitter user timelines into one request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5510619/147564) they said about list and bot account, but from my understanding twitter limited 20 lists fro 1 account, so this seem not practical for > 20 users based app.

Answer (score 1):

The list idea is just fine. You don't have to create new list to every user in your app. Add unique users you want to follow to non-full list (1 list can have up to 500 members) or create new list. Then poll all your lists few times an hour - then just sort out which screen_names to show to which your users.

I have managed to collect the statuses of ~55000 twitter users by using only 6 bot accounts.